# Loader doesn't start after calling initLoader()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I have a fragment, and want to start a loader when a button is clicked:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public void onActivityCreated() {
        super.onActivityCreated();

        Button btn = ...;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getLoaderManager().initLoader(500, null, mMyCallback);
            }
        });
    }  

    private LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> mMyCallback = new  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String>() {

        @Override
        public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            Log.e(TAG, "LoaderCallback.onCreateLoader().");
            return new MyLoader(getActivity());
        }
    }
}

public class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {
    public MyLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public String loadInBackground() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Hi, running.");
        return "terrific.";
    }
}
```

After clicking the button, I can see my callback's onCreateLoader method called, but the created loader never actually starts. Do we need to call forceLoad() on the loader itself to get it to actually start? None of the sample posts do this,

Thanks

Answer (score 32):

You need to implement `onStartLoading()` and call `forceLoad()` somewhere in the method.

See this post for more information: [**Implementing Loaders (part 3)**](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html)

Comment: What should i actually implent in forceLoad() method?

Comment: @Manikanta My answer says you should _call_ `forceLoad()`, not implement it.

Comment: Actually i want to update my ListView continuously from SQLiteOpenHelper, I don't know What way is preferable. Can you please suggest any way?

Answer (score 6):

In my experience it never worked unless I used `forceLoad()`.

You may find the answer to this previous question helpful:
[Loaders in Android Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920930/loaders-in-android-honeycomb)

Answer (score 4):

Three important points regarding Loaders are:

1. Always Use `forceLoad()` method while initialising Loaders. For Example:

   ```
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(500, null, mMyCallback).forceLoad();
   ```
2. Always implement `onStartLoading()`. This function will automatically be called by `LoaderManager` when the associated fragment/activity is being started.
3. Make sure the ID of the loader is unique otherwise new Loader will not be called.

If there is still a problem you can check the state of loader by calling the `isStarted()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a reference to the instance of the loader you create in the method `onCreateLoader`. Then, to refresh it, call `yourLoader.onContentChanged();`

Comment: OMG, you literally just fixed my entire problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 1 loader in the same activity, make sure their id differs. I lost few hours to figure it out :)